# Google chart change bar color

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, charts, google-visualization

i am using google chart api to show a chart on a bootstrap modal with framework Laravel, i'm having an issue because i'm not beein able to change the colour of the bar and put one blue and the other one green, another issue is that at the right it only put me the name of une of the bars(RX).

Here is my js code:

```
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  // google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart(nombre, unidad, tipo, valor, media) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'RX');     
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

    data.addRows([
      ['Tú', parseInt(valor), valor+' '+unidad],
      ['Media', parseFloat(media), parseInt(media)+' '+unidad],
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,1,2]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(view, {
      // height: 400,
      // width: 600,
      series: {
        0: {
          type: 'bars'
        },
        1: {
          type: 'line',
          color: 'grey',
          lineWidth: 0,
          pointSize: 0,
          visibleInLegend: false
        }
      },
      vAxis: {
        maxValue: 100,
        minValue: 0,
      }
    });
    $("#myModalLabel").empty();
    $("#myModalLabel").append(tipo+" - "+nombre);
    $("#modalChart").modal();
  }
```

Here is the chart that i get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can write your drawchart function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
    ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
    ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
    ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
    ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
 }
 </script>
```

For more https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#labeling-columns